# It's your turn now!

Tags: mathematics, cipher, pattern, lateral-thinking

**What is the simple rule behind these three relations below?**

$F$ $\rightarrow$ $C$ :: $R$ $\rightarrow$ $I$ $\rightarrow$ $\sqrt{F}$ ::
$IA$ $\rightarrow$ $D$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rule

> translate to number $A\rightarrow 1,B\rightarrow 2$ etc. turn upside down $6\mapsto 9,18\mapsto 81$ etc. and take the square root.

One-by.one

> $6(\mapsto 9)\rightarrow 3$
>  
>  $18(\mapsto 81)\rightarrow 9(\mapsto 6)\rightarrow \sqrt 6$
>  
>  $91(\mapsto 16)\rightarrow 4$

Comment: Yes, well done!